# how to query analyze int values

Tags: solr, lucene, schema

I have an integer value in SOLR/Lucen.
When I search for values in it, people might add a prefix to the query:
The field is an ID. So for item with id=900, people might search "900" or "it900" or "it-900"  Since this is how we represent items (categort +'-'+id).

Right now, I strip all none numeric characters in my code. Seems to me logically there should be a simple way in the SOLR schema to make this happen.

I tried defining a query analyzer for an integer field. But, Lucen does not like analyzers for INT fields 
error message:

```
FieldType: TrieIntField (int) does not support specifying an analyzer
```

The field is (The analyzer is not working, as written above)

```
        <fieldType name="int" class="solr.TrieIntField" precisionStep="0" omitNorms="true" positionIncrementGap="0">
            <analyzer type="query">
                <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
                <filter class="solr.PatternReplaceFilterFactory" pattern="(\d+)" replacement="$1" />
            </analyzer> 
        </fieldType>
```

Any idea how I define this?

Comment: Can you specify the filter on (say) a text field instead, and then copy the contents of that string field to an int field? That seems like the simplest way of handling it.

Comment: It would work, if this was an issue during indexing. Alas, the issue is during querying. unless, there is a way to do it for querying too?

Comment: I take it you are not able to reindex? Because if you're able to reindex you can follow the procedure I outlined above.

Comment: Sorry, your process does seem to work, I need more tests though, can u put this as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you specify the filter on (say) a text field instead, and then copy the contents of that string field to an int field? That seems like the simplest way of handling it.